# Add 'fade' effect to Elementor Loop Carousel widget

Tags: swiper.js, elementor

Unlike other sliders/carousels within Elementor, the Loop Carousel doesn't allow you to change the transition type, and only scrolls across.

Apparently all the sliders are powered by swiper.js so I tried to add effect="fade" to the .swiper-container html just in the inspector, but it didn't have any effect.

Does anyone know of hacking this somehow to have a fade transition, as that should be basic functionality for such a Swiper?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', { effect: 'fade' });

https://swiperjs.com/get-started